# How to fix cannot convert value of type Result<SuccessType<A>, Error> to closure result type Result<Success, Failure> Swift

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I'm trying to map over Swift's Result type to produce a new Result of a different type but it isn't type checking, and is throwing the error:

`error: cannot convert value of type Result<ParseSuccess<B>, ParseError> to closure result type Result<Success, Failure>`

I've tried using a switch on the result and matching on the .success and .failure but I get a similar type checking error. I've also tried specifying the input and return types explicitly with no luck.

I've  replicated the code in other languages I'm a little more familiar with (F# and Kotlin) and it seems to type check there.

The swift compiler shows a sqiggly under this line:
`return self.apply(input).map { result in ParseSuccess(transform(result.data), result.input) }`

Where am I going wrong with this code?

```swift
import Foundation

class ParseError : Error {
    let err: String
    init(_ err: String) {
        self.err = err
    }
}

class ParseSuccess<A> {
    let data: A
    let input: Substring

    init(_ data: A, _ input: Substring) {
        self.data = data
        self.input = input
    }
}

class Parser<A> {
    let fn: (Substring) -> Result<ParseSuccess<A>, ParseError>

    init(_ fn: @escaping (Substring) -> Result<ParseSuccess<A>, ParseError>) {
        self.fn = fn
    }

    func apply(_ input: Substring) -> Result<ParseSuccess<A>, ParseError> {
        return self.fn(input)
    }

    func map<B>(_ transform: @escaping (A) -> B) -> Parser<B> {
        return Parser { (input) in 
            return self.apply(input).map { result in 
 ParseSuccess(transform(result.data), result.input) }
        }
    }      
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm sure this is probably not the best way to start writing a parser combinator, but I've gotten caught up in trying to figure out where I went wrong here!

Thank you

Comment: BTW, your parse error and success types are probably more appropriately representable as structs. In the case of `ParseError`, it's probably even best to use an `enum`, and use discrete cases rather than differing `err` string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird behaviour of the unqualified used of `Paraser` in the line `return Parser {`. When a generic type is mentioned in its unqualified form, within the body of the generic type's declaration, the type parameters are inferred to be unchanged. For example, a function on `Array<T>` can return simply `Array`, and the `T` is implied to be the same as the value of `T` for `self.` Needless to say, I'm not a huge fan of this behaviour.

Changing it to `return Parser<B> { ...` solves the issue.

---

Here's how I found the issue. When working with generics errors, I always try to insert a ton of type annotations to "pin down" the data types, to confirm that the compiler and me are on the same page.

I first wrote:

```
func map<B>(_ transform: @escaping (A) -> B) -> Parser<B> {
    return Parser { (input) in 
        return self.apply(input).map { result in 
            let newData: ParseSuccess<B> = transform(result.data)
            return ParseSuccess(newData, result.input)
        }
    }
}
```

At which point the error changed to:

```
Untitled 2.swift:32:10: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'Parser<A>' to return type 'Parser<B>'
                return Parser { (input) in 
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```